# mixins is not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie to reactjs , I am playing around with some of reactjs properties.I am unable to find the reason why `this.props.food` is not showing(but the console value "testing the mixins" is showing in console) the assigned value.What is the mistake I am doing.Here is glimpse of my code.If it isn't sufficient enough let me know.

```
var InputBox=React.createClass({
  mixins: [UselessMixin],
  render:function(){
    return  <div className="container">
          <div className="form-group"> 
            <label for="usr">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="usr" />
            <b>My favourite food is </b>{this.props.food}
          </div>
        </div>  
    }
})


var UselessMixin = {
  getDefaultProps: function () {
    console.log("testing the mixins");
    return {food: "dosa"};
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need define `UselessMixin` before component declaration, because now `InputBox` does not know about `UselessMixin` and gets `undefined`

```
var UselessMixin = {
  getDefaultProps: function () {
    console.log("testing the mixins");
    return {food: "dosa"};
  }
};

var InputBox = React.createClass({
  mixins: [UselessMixin],
  render: function() {
    return <div className="container">
      <div className="form-group"> 
        <label htmlFor="usr">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="usr" />
        <b>My favourite food is </b>{this.props.food}
      </div>
    </div>  
  }
})
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/37251/)

Comment: Thanks @ Alexander .That was a simple and quick too.